# Change the full title on a single page (Drupal)

Tags: drupal-7

I need to change the title of a single page within a Drupal site.

Right now I have it set up so that in hook_preprocess_page I'm calling drupal_set_title(). That's fine, except that it leaves the site name in the title. How can I change the complete title, site name and all? I don't want the site name to appear on this one page.

Answer (score 0):

i think you can change the title by use

```
drupal_set_title(check_plain($node->title));
```

may be this module help you
 "[Page Title](http://drupal.org/project/page_title)"

Comment: That's what I did. I leaves the site name appended to whatever you pass to drupal_set_title().